# Makefiles in eclipse and their path

Tags: eclipse, path, makefile

I'm trying to build a project with a specific compiler in Eclipse, and I'm using a Makefile to do the dirty work -- only problem is that it seems as if Eclipse doesn't share the same paths as my bash sessions. I've set .bash_profile and .profile (apparently Mac likes .profile just as much as .bash_profile), but neither of the exports that I've included are getting picked up. Do I need to manually set some symlinks in my /usr/bin or something like that? Or is there a way to manually set paths in eclipse?

Comment: Do you use [CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/)?

Comment: Yes. [Minimum character limit...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.bash_profile` and `.profile` are read by `bash` when session is started. So you need to change the build command to `bash -l -c "make"`.

Comment: What is the output of your build? Can you provide relevant console output?

Answer (score 0):

Edited the Makefile and just added the absolute path:

```
PATH = /Users/me/yagarto/yagarto-4.6.2/bin/
TRGT = $(PATH)arm-none-eabi-
```